# Get Any Interface's Router Address

Tags: networking, router, netstat

How can I know what the router's address is when I am on multiple interface?
I know by using netstat -rn I can have the dominating interface's gateway, which is the router's address. But what about other interface.

For my case, I am on eth0 and wlan0 on different router, OS chooses eth0 as default (and I cannot find wlan0's gateway), but is there a universal way that I can query an interface's router address?

```
$ netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlan0

$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b4:b5:2f:32:f3:22  
      inet addr:192.168.1.132  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::b6b5:2fff:fe32:f322/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:22 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:53 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:3035 (3.0 KB)  TX bytes:9857 (9.8 KB)
      Interrupt:17 Memory:d4400000-d4420000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:569 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:569 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:53950 (53.9 KB)  TX bytes:53950 (53.9 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 60:67:20:00:56:6c  
      inet addr:192.168.2.115  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::6267:20ff:fe00:566c/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:8152 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:4030 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:6316155 (6.3 MB)  TX bytes:574275 (574.2 KB)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the `ip route` command.  If you invoke `ip route` on my server, which has two ethernet cards, "enp3s0" and "enp3s8", you get this:

```
1001 % ip route
default via 10.0.0.1 dev enp3s8
10.0.0.0/24 dev enp3s8  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.3
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp3s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.148
```

That shows you all the routes.  It seems you can get a route for a specific device name like this:

```
[root@splunge ~]# ip route list dev enp3s8
default via 10.0.0.1
10.0.0.0/24  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.3
```

The "default via" line shows you the router's IP address.

That's all on an Arch linux box.  `ip` is part of the `iproute2` package, and it's `/usr/bin/ip`.  On an older RHEL box, it's `/sbin/ip`, and I have no idea what package it's from.

Comment: Do you know how I can get the router address for enp3s0 in your case? Which is not the dominant connection right now.

Comment: @LingyuanHe - You could do: `ip route | grep enp3s0 | awk '{print $9}'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `traceroute` and specify the device to use with `-i`, then the next hop will be the router connected to that device.

Comment: Only if the next hop is already in the routing table. This doesn't help discover it.

Answer (score 0):

Best way I found for that matter is to print the dhcp configuration files, found on /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.(interface).leases, and look for the routers definition there